# Field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform flutter (this topic is different)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

First of all, i can't solve this title solutions which are already exist in stackoverflow, so i decided to open this topic.

it gives: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform
, this error

how can i solve this? What is the problem, i can't find it, doc(dataPost.reference.parent.parent.id) may be problem but i am not sure.

note: There are users, and if user create any new post, then firestore create 'Posts' section in user uid's. I want to get all posts for homepage...

my codes and screenshot here:

```
class HomePageBodyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('Posts').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshotPost) {
        if (snapshotPost.hasError) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        if (snapshotPost.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        if (!snapshotPost.hasData) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }

        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshotPost.data.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final dataPost = snapshotPost.data.docs[index];
              if (!snapshotPost.hasData) {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
              return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('Users')
                    .doc(dataPost.reference.parent.parent.id)
                    .get(),
                builder:
                    (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshotUser) {
                  final dataUser = snapshotUser.data;
                  if (snapshotUser.hasError) {
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }

                  if (snapshotUser.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    return homePageCard(
                      context,
                      dataPost: dataPost,
                      dataUser: dataUser,
                    );
                  }
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                },
              );
            });
      });
}
```

homePageCard which has information about user and post:

```
  Widget homePageCard(BuildContext context,
        {dynamic dataUser, dynamic dataPost}) {
      return Card(
        child: Container(
          width: 85,
          height: 190,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.teal[100]),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 11.0, left: 8),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 12,
                            backgroundImage:
                                NetworkImage(dataUser['profilePhotoUrl'])),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 11.0, left: 3),
                        child: Text(dataUser['username']),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Center(
                          child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0, top: 11.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "dataPost['postDate'].toString()",
                          style:
                              const TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 13),
                        ),
                      )),
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Divider(
                          thickness: 0.3,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          indent: 0,
                          height: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Divider(
                  thickness: 0.3,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  indent: 0,
                  height: 1,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  dataPost["postTitle"],
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0, right: 18.0),
                  child: Text(
                    '\$' + dataPost['gamePrice'.toString()],
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 24,
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 3.0, bottom: 5.0),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.my_location,
                      color: Colors.black54,
                      size: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0, bottom: 3.0),
                      child: Text("dataPost['postCategory']",
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12,
                            color: Colors.black54,
                          )))
                ],
              ),
              const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen okey you did it , thx